# Doubts regarding gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have some doubts regarding gmapping. On the wiki page, it is stated that gmapping make use of both laserscan and odometry data to build a map. However,it seems that the slam_mapping node only subscribe to “scan” topic but not to “odom” topic. So, is it that we only need to set the “odom_frame” parameter when launching gmapping to “odom” so that the gmapping receive odometry data? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50231/doubts-regarding-gmapping/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) receives the odometry information in the form of a transform from the `odom` frame to the `base_link` frame. You need another package (for example [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf)) publishing that transform in order for gmapping to work.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-11**:
Thanks Ivan! I have always thought of odometry information as a stream of msg. Seems like I am wrong.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-11**:
Odometry is a stream of messages on the /odom topic. But in ROS, an odometry node is also supposed to continuously publish the transform odom -> base_link and that's what, for instance, the robot_pose_ekf node does after fusing /odom and IMU data.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-11**:
I see. That answered  my queries. Thanks!